Phantom lines on table when zoom in
Pre-requires: all table borders should be set to 0 or none.
When zoom in via touchpad you can see a background color trought small gaps between table cells.
Example table from Angular Material Documentation with darkcyan background-color on table header cells
You can test on this JSFiddle or Table | Angular Material Docs or any other documentation with tables.
In case when all columns have a fixed width that gaps appear also when zooming via browser zoom (ctrl + mouse scroll || ctrl + "plus"(+)
Tested in Google Chrome, Opera, Microsoft Edge
Anyone knows how to fix it?
Set cellpadding=0 and cellspacing=0 doesn't helps.

Please could you make a runnable snippet within the question (use <> icon in the editor) as external sites can disappear so rendering your question useless for future readers.
